# ABM under python with advanced visualization

Tags: python, netlogo, pycuda, agent-based-modeling, mayavi

sorry if this all seem nooby and unclear, but I'm currently learning Netlogo to model agent-based collective behavior and would love to hear some advice on alternative software choices. My main thing is that I'd very much like to take advantage of PyCuda since, from what I understand, it enables parallel computation. However, does that mean I still have to write the numerical script in some other environment and implement the visuals in yet another one???

If so, my questions are:

1. What numerical package should I use? PyEvolve, DEAP, or something else? It appears that PyEvolve is no longer being developed and DEAP is just a wrapper on the outdated(?) EAP.
2. Graphic-wise, I find mayavi2 and vtk promising. The problem is, none of the numerical package seems to bind to these readily. Is there no better alternative than to save the numerical output to datafile and feed them into, say, mayavi2?
3. Another option is to generate the data via Netlogo and feed them into a graphing package from (2). Is there any disadvantage to doing this?

Thank you so much for shedding light on this confusion.

Comment: Have you looked at `scipy` or `sage` -- these both work with `pymatplotlib`

Comment: Is parallel computation a necessity?

Comment: Not necessarily. However, I imagine it would hugely boost the simulation's efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly do not want to use CUDA unless you are running into a significant performance problem. In general CUDA is best used for solving floating point linear algebra problems. If you are looking for a framework built around parallel computations, I'd look towards OpenCL which can take advantage of GPUs if needed..

In terms of visualization, I'd strongly suggest targeting a a specific data interchange format and then letting some other program do that rendering for you. The only reason I'd use something like VTK is if for some reason you need more control over the visualization process or you are looking for a real time solution.

Comment: Thank you! That is wonderfully helpful. Can you however clarify for me what you mean by "specific data interchange format"? Would TVTK be such an example and Mayavi be the program that renders it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best choice for visualization would be to use an intermediate format and do it in another program. But for performance, i'd rather configure a JVM for a cluster and run NetLogo on it. I've not tried it yet but i'm thinking seriously to try NetLogo on a Beowulf style cluster.

BTW, there is an ABM platform called [Repast](http://repast.sourceforge.net/) that is [said to have Python interface](http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_3/index.html) if you're planning to implement your code in Python.

Comment: Can you give me a python example of an "intermediate format" and "another program" in which to run it?